# Thread never gets the lock (pthread_mutex_lock)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, locking, mutex

## Story

According to the man page https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock

> The mutex object referenced by mutex shall be locked by calling pthread_mutex_lock(). If the mutex is already locked, the calling thread shall block until the mutex becomes available.

I have a program with a thread. Here is the program flow:

1. The **main process** and the **thread** always call `pthread_mutex_lock` inside of a loop.
2. When the **main process** is holding the lock, the **thread** which is asking for lock, blocks (waiting for lock to be granted).
3. When the **main process** releases the lock with `pthread_mutex_unlock`, the **thread** should suddenly get the lock.
4. When the **main process** asks for the lock again, the **main process** should wait for the **thread** to release the lock.

The problem is that, at point 3, the **thread** does not suddenly get the lock as soon as the **main process** releases the lock. The main process gets it first when it calls to `pthread_mutex_lock` in the next loop cycle (at point 4).

How to deal with this situation?

## Question

How can I make the **thread** get the lock as soon as the **main process** releases the lock?

## Simple code to reproduce the problem

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t my_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *
my_thread(void *p)
{
  (void)p;

  while (1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
    printf("The thread is holding the lock...\n");
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
  }
}

int
main()
{
  pthread_t t;

  pthread_create(&t, NULL, my_thread, NULL);
  pthread_detach(t);

  while (1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
    printf("The main process is holding the lock...\n");
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);
  }
}
```

## Compile and Run

```
gcc test.c -o test -lpthread
./test
```

## Expected result

```
The main process is holding the lock...
The thread is holding the lock...
The main process is holding the lock...
The thread is holding the lock...
The main process is holding the lock...
The thread is holding the lock...
The main process is holding the lock...
...
```

## Actual result

```
The main process is holding the lock...
The main process is holding the lock...
The main process is holding the lock...
The main process is holding the lock...
The main process is holding the lock...
The main process is holding the lock...
The main process is holding the lock...
...
```

## Calls story in order

```
main   -> [1] call lock (get the lock)
thread -> [2] call lock (waiting for main to unlock)
main   -> [3] call unlock
thread -> [4] (still does not get the lock from [2], why? even though it has been unlocked?)
main   -> [5] lock (get the lock again)
thread -> [6] (still does not get the lock from [2])
main   -> [7] call unlock
thread -> [8] (still does not get the lock from [2], why? even though it has been unlocked?)
main   -> [9] lock (get the lock again)
... and so on ...
```

## Summary

`pthread_mutex_lock` does not guarantee the order of lock requests.

Comment: When the calling thread blocks waiting for the lock to be released, it's not guaranteed that it's actually going to *acquire* the lock, only that it's going to compete for it. After the main thread releases the lock, it *immediately* tries to re-acquire, and this appears to be fast enough that it's competing with the other thread, and lock acquisition is not guaranteed to be done in order. Adding a tiny delay in the main thread after release would probably give you the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pthread_mutex_lock` guarantees that it will lock until the mutex becomes available. That does not mean that each lock() call enters a queue and is guaranteed to get the mutex lock next. It only means that nobody else will have the lock at the same time.

If you require a certain order, an option would be to use *condition variables*. That way, you can have a flag that is set to the next member which should get the mutex. You can then wait for the mutex until the value is as expected. See https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait.

Alternatively, if your example has sleeps in it anyway as above, you can just move the sleep after the unlock() call. While that is not strictly speaking a guarantee, it will most definitely do the trick for a simple test. I do not recommend this approach for anything more serious/complex though.

**EDIT**: As Shawn correctly added, you can also use `pthread_yield` ([1](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html)) to allow another thread to acquire the mutex if you don't care which other thread it is. Some intricacies with yielding are described in [sched_yield(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html).

PS: I would comment, but my rep is now high enough yet :)

Comment: @Shawn No. `pthread_yield()` [is not portable because it's no longer POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) and [there's no guarantee at all that would work anyway](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html#NOTES).  If you want a specific order, **you** must code it up yourself.  Or use a third-party library.

Comment: [Interesting thread on `pthread_yield()`/`sched_yield()`](https://comp.programming.threads.narkive.com/iRYqp6xQ/posix-threads-pthread-yeld): "... `pthread_yield()` was never standard ... Really, if you're depending on `pthread_yield()` to do anything, you've
probably got a logic problem. Scheduling is not synchronization; it's
just scheduling. ..."

Comment: It just gives another thread a chance to acquire the lock. If you want strict alternation or something, yeah, it's not suitable.

Comment: @Shawn **NO it doesnt guarantee that at all**.  From that same link:  "consider
pthread_yield() to be nothing more than a "scheduler hint" saying
essentially "Oh mighty scheduler, shoulds't thou thinkest in thine
wisdom that thy might taketh from me my processor in the near future, I
beseech thou to do it now."

And it may do it, or it may shrug its little virtual shoulders and go on
about its business. You don't know, your code can't tell,"

Comment: @Shawn, Naw, happens to work, which means there are some number of system states ( loads, interrupt rates, etc...), scheduling parameters which will cause it to fail.

Comment: Just throw a unit around two semaphores.  The other mutex/timer/yield abuses are just bad, it's that simple.  Stop abusing mutex!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 'fairlock' as an example; you can do better:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct fairlock FairLock;
struct fairlock {
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t  cv;
    long scount;
    long wcount;
};



#define err(x,v) do { int t; if ((t=(x)) != (v)) { \
    error(__FILE__,__LINE__, #x, t, (v)); \
}} while (0)

static void error(char *fn, int lno, char *s, long x, long v) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d %s returned %ld rather than %ld\n",
        fn, lno, s, x, v);
    exit(1);
}


void Lock(FairLock *f) {

    err(pthread_mutex_lock(&f->lock), 0);
    long me = f->scount++;
    while (f->wcount != me) {
        err(pthread_cond_wait(&f->cv, &f->lock), 0);
    }
    err(pthread_mutex_unlock(&f->lock), 0);

}

void UnLock(FairLock *f) {
    err(pthread_mutex_lock(&f->lock), 0);
    if (f->scount > f->wcount) {
        f->wcount++;
        err(pthread_cond_broadcast(&f->cv), 0);
    }
    err(pthread_mutex_unlock(&f->lock), 0);
}

FairLock *NewLock(void) {
    FairLock *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if (p != 0) {
        err(pthread_mutex_init(&p->lock, 0),0);
        err(pthread_cond_init(&p->cv, 0),0);
        p->scount = p->wcount = 0;
    }
    return p;
}

void DoneLock(FairLock *f) {
    err(pthread_mutex_destroy(&f->lock), 0);
    err(pthread_cond_destroy(&f->cv), 0);
}
```

And your testlock.c changed to utilize it; again there is room for improvement, but you should be able to stick sleeps just about anywhere and it will remain fair....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "fairlock.c"

FairLock *my;

void *
my_thread(void *p)
{
  while (1) {
    Lock(my);
    printf("%s is holding the lock...\n", p);
    UnLock(my);
  }
}



int
main()
{
  pthread_t t;
  my = NewLock();
  pthread_create(&t, NULL, my_thread, "one");
  pthread_detach(t);
  pthread_create(&t, NULL, my_thread, "two");
  pthread_detach(t);
  pthread_create(&t, NULL, my_thread, "three");
  pthread_detach(t);
  pthread_create(&t, NULL, my_thread, "four");
  pthread_detach(t);
  pthread_create(&t, NULL, my_thread, "five");
  pthread_detach(t);

  while (1) {
    Lock(my);
    printf("main process is holding the lock...\n");
    UnLock(my);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR Version:

The *very next thing* that either of your two loops does after releasing the lock is to try to acquire it again.

When there's a race between thread A which has just released a lock and thread B which has been blocked, waiting for the lock, thread A almost always will win because thread A already is running, and thread B still is "asleep."

Releasing the lock doesn't instantaneously "wake up" the waiting thread.  All it does is change the status of the other thread from "waiting for the lock" to "waiting to be assigned a CPU to run on." Some time real soon after, the Scheduler will get around to restoring the context of thread B on another CPU, and thread B will start running, but by then it will be too late. Thread A will have already re-locked the lock.